# Maximizing a sum of products restricted to another sum of products

Tags: optimization, summation

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}^{\geq 3}$ be a constant and $S=\{e, h_2,\ldots,h_n\}$ a set of variables where each $h_i\in\mathbb{N}^{\geq0}$ and $e\in\{0, 1\}$. The problem is: $$
\begin{split}
\min\quad& m=\sum_{i=2}^n ih_i\\
\text{s.t.}\quad&
n=e+\sum_{i=2}^n (i+1)h_i
\end{split}
$$

**Edited. Solution:** I'd like to know if there's any, simpler, way to reach to the same conclusion; specifically, which already known-thereoms do exists that I can use to shorten the proof, because I have expend to much time thinking how to remove, in an elegant way, the remainders as variables. After all, this is very similar to the Knapsack problem but not quite the same because of the equality restriction, so there must be plenty of well-known results out there, but I haven't been able to find a suitable one for me.

**NOTE:** Writting $n=\underline{a}q+r$ means that $q$ and $r$ are the quotient and remainder of $n/a$ respectively.

Given a solution $S=\{e, h_2, \ldots, h_n\}$, let's call $H=\sum_{i=2}^nh_i$. Then: $$
n=e+\sum_{i=2}^n(i+1)h_i=e+H+m\iff m=n-(e+H)
$$

Which means minimizing $m$ implies maximizing $e+H$. Knowing its $H$ and $e$, any solution $S$ can be simplified to $S'=\{e', h'_a, h'_{a+1}\}$ with any other $h'_x=0$ (so they are omitted) by expressing $n$ as $$
n=\underline{H}(a+1)+r = h'_{a+1}(a+2)+h'_a(a+1)+e'
$$

where $H=h'_{a+1}+h'_a$, $e'=e$, and $r=h'_{a+1}+e'$. Notice that $n\geq 3\implies H\geq 1\implies n\geq 3H$; $a+1\geq 3$, and so $a\geq 2$ is a valid variable index and $S'$ a valid solution. This solution $S'$ is equivalent to $S$ because $H$ and $e$, and consequently $m$ and $n$, haven't changed.

That means the set of simplified solutions is complete for the problem, which can be reestated as, given $n\in\mathbb{N}^{\geq3}$, $$
\begin{split}
\max\quad& H+e\\
\text{s.t.}\quad&
n=\underline{H}(a+1)+r\\
&e\leq \min(1, r)\\
&a\geq 2
\end{split}\implies\begin{split}
\max\quad & H+\min(1,r)\\
\text{s.t.}\quad & n=\underline{H}(a+1)+r\\
& a\geq 2
\end{split}\implies\begin{split}
\max\quad & H\\
\text{s.t.}\quad & n=\underline{H}(a+1)+r\\
& a\geq 2
\end{split}
$$ where $H$ is our only variable now. The last step is explained because, since $\min(1, r)\in\{0, 1\}$, decreasing $H$ never increases $H+\min(1, r)$, and thus increasing $H$ doesn't affect the optimality of $H+\min(1, r)$. In other words, we only need to optimize $H$.

Now consider that an optimal $H$ gives an $r$ that is also remainder of $n/(a+1)$. Otherwise, $r=k\underline{(a+1)}+q$ and thus $H$ can grow by $k\geq 1$ units with $a$ fixed. That means the set of solutions where $r\geq a+1$ contains no optimal solution. Reestating again: $$
\begin{split}
\max\quad & H\\
\text{s.t.}\quad & n=H\underline{(a+1)}+r\\
& a\geq 2
\end{split}\implies\begin{split}
\max\quad & \left\lfloor\frac{n}{a+1}\right\rfloor\\
\text{s.t.}\quad & a\geq 2
\end{split}\implies a=2
$$

The optimal solution is then (where $r$ is the remainder of $n/3$), $$
\begin{split}
H\quad&= \lfloor n/3\rfloor = (n-r)/3\\
e\quad&= \min(1, r)\\
h_3\quad&= r-e\\
h_2\quad& = H-h_3 = \lfloor n/3\rfloor - (r-e)\\
m\quad& = 2h_2+3h_3 = 2H+r-e
\end{split}
$$

where $m$ can be further simplified by $$
m=2\frac{n-r}{3}+r-e=\frac{2n+r-3e}{3}=\left\lfloor
\frac{2n+(r-3e)-(r-3e)}{3}\right\rfloor$$$$
\iff \boxed{m= \left\lfloor\frac{2n}{3}\right\rfloor}
$$

The last step is explained because, since $2n+r-3e$ divides $3$, adding any amount between $0$ and $2$ won't change its value when inside of the floor function. Since $r-3e\in\{0, -2, -1\}$ for $r=0,1,2$ respectively, adding $-(r-3e)$ is a valid amount.

Comment: I do believe that your problem is ill-posed if don't also assume that $\sum h_i$ converges; you need at least $h_i\to 0$ when $i\to\infty$. Problably that since $n = \sum (i+1)h_i <\infty$ you can deduce some conditions on the convergence of $\sum h_i$, that will, ultimately, lead you to something like "$h_i$'s must be decreasing".

Comment: @FlorianIngels question edited.

Comment: @FlorianIngels I made the question a bit simplier by restricting $H$ to be a finite set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s handle the case where there’s no $e$ and the variables don’t have to be integers first. In that case, since all the integers are unbounded above, there’d be an optimal solution where only one variable is nonzero. Given a solution where two variables are nonzero, increasing one of those variables slightly and decreasing the other accordingly will only either increase $H$, or decrease $H$, or keep $H$ constant. And since everything’s linear, you can move in whichever direction is best until one of those variables is 0, without decreasing $H$. So in the continuous case, you just have to choose which $h_i$ is the best. Clearly, it’s $h_2$, so you’d take $h_2=n/3$.

Then you just have to handle the integer restriction, and put $e$ back in. Clearly, if $n=3k+1$, you take $e=1$ and keep your solution from the continuous case. If $n=3k$, you can take $h_2=n/3$ and $e=0$, and you can check that no other integer solution is better. Similarly, if $n=3k+2$, you can take $h_3=1,e=1,h_2=(n-2)/3$, and show that no other integer solution is better.

Comment: The problem with your first part about increasing/decreasing H, is that you would have to show that decreasing a variable of lower index to increase a variable of higher index will make $H$ grow slower than the other way around, because each variable have a factor equal to its index + 1 regarding the restriction on $n$. And the part of "show that no integer solution is better" also requires an extra wording (because I have to show it). So I don't know if adding what is implicit to your proof to get the whole thing would make the proof shorter than mine.

Comment: When you're just showing that at most one of the $h_i$ is positive, it doesn't matter whether increasing a higher or a lower variable increases $H$ - as long as at least one of those options doesn't decrease $H$, you can move in that direction to set one of the variables to 0. Since this is finite, you can repeat the process until all the variables except one are 0. Once you've established that the only solutions are those where at most one variable is nonzero, you can calculate that $m=\frac{i}{i+1}n$ if $h_i$ is nonzero.

Comment: You are right. Actually, your argument applies even for the discrete case. If $g$ is the greatest index such that $h_g>0$, and $l$ the lowest index such that $h_l>0$, and $g > l + 1$, you can always construct a new solution $S'$ with $h'_g = h_g - 1$, $h'_{g-1}=h_{g-1}+1$, $h'_l = h_l - 1$ and $h'_{l+1}=h_{l+1}+1$. With that modification, $S'$ preserves $H$, $e$, $n$ and $m$, and by applying this procedure repeatedly you end with two variables $>0$, $h_a$ and $h_{a+1}$, where $a$ is the quotient of $n/H$, and so the set of solutions using at most two variables represents the problem.